# Redirect to another domain url using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

following is the process which I am following to redirect the domain

> 1. cy.visit('website URL') by passing basic arguments for authentication pop-up
> 2. click on the button

clicking on the button is redirecting to a different domain URL.(again it's showing basic authentication pop-up)

Answer (score 2):

Because cypress is not supporting this, you can start the test with visiting the domain where button is redirecting.

This is one of the disadvantages of cypress.

Comment: I can't visit that domain without clicking on the button in the first domain

Comment: @SaiDeepti ask the developers where it redirects, or check the web developer tools and see where it redirects.